# Why does $I_N + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}AD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ have eigenvalues in the range [0, 2]?

Tags: papers, convolution, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, linear-algebra

In [Semi-supervised classification with Graph Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02907.pdf), I am unable to understand a few things.

Given an undirected graph having

- adjacency matrix $A$,
- degree matrix $D_{ii} = \sum_j A_{ij}$,
- normalized graph laplacian $L = I_N + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}AD^{-\frac{1}{2}} = U \Lambda U^T$, where $\lambda_{max} \approx 2$ (see page 3, 2nd paragraph, not sure which matrix they are talking about)

Then, $I_N + D^{-\frac{1}{2}}AD^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ has eigenvalues in the range [0, 2]. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof of the first statement can be found in these [Lecture Notes](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6334/Fall2016/lecture7.pdf).

Have a look of the Proof of the *Claim 1*.

Concerning the *renormalization trick* I do not see easy way to justify this statement. [The paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07153.pdf) claims:

> i.e. adding self-loops to the graph, improves accuracy, and we
> demonstrate that this method effectively shrinks the graph spectral
> domain, resulting in a low-pass-type filter when applied to SGC.